# Why in this one recipe parsley is used in 2 different ways?

Tags: pasta, shrimp

I found a "Shrimp and Pasta" Recipe [here](http://southernfood.about.com/od/shrimprecipes/r/bl10727i.htm).  It's a nice and simple, but I don't quite understand the way it uses parsley.  Why part of the parsley is fried with shrimp and the rest are just mixed with pasta?  And what does TB mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsley is both a flavoring herb and a decorative element for plating the finished dish.  By adding it during the cooking, it imparts flavor to the shrimp.  By adding it to the finished dish, it provides color and flavor.  The cooked parsley will have a slightly different taste to it than the fresh parsley.  This is how cooks layer the flavors in a dish.

TB stands for Tablespoon.

Comment: Thanks.  BTW, should I mince the parsley before frying it?